# vb.net loop through selected items Listbox

Tags: vb.net, listbox, selecteditem

I am trying to loop through all selected items of my ListBox1. The problem is my code keeps the same `SearchFolder = ItemSelected`

```
If ListBox1.SelectedIndex > -1 Then
                For Each Item As Object In ListBox1.SelectedItems

                    Dim ItemSelected = CType(ListBox1.SelectedItem.Item("Path"), String)
                    SearchFolder = ItemSelected

                    Dim dirInfo As New IO.DirectoryInfo(SearchFolder)
                    Dim files As IO.FileInfo() = dirInfo.GetFiles()
                    Dim file As IO.FileInfo

                    docImage = (ImageList1.Images.Count - 1)
                    Dim items As New List(Of ListViewItem)

                    For Each file In files
                        Dim filename As String = file.Name.ToString

                        If file.Extension = ".pdf" Then
                            foundList = PDFManipulation.GetTextFromPDF2(SearchFolder + filename, SearchRegX)
                            If foundList = True Then
                                items.Add(New ListViewItem(New String() {"", filename.ToString}, docImage))
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next
                    ListView1.Items.AddRange(items.ToArray)

                Next
            End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the line:

> Dim ItemSelected = CType(ListBox1.SelectedItem.Item("Path"), String)

You are ignoring the item in the loop and going for the first selected item.

You should replace this with:

```
Dim ItemSelected = CType(Item("Path"), String)
```

The variable `Item` is one you declared in the `For Loop`